# Create a function called numbaOne that returns the first element of an array that is passed in as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

This should work for an array of any size.

My solution:

```
var numbaOne = [1,2,3];
console.log(numbaOne0);
```

Why doesn't that work? I tried it in repl.it and it worked.

Comment: There is no function there...

Comment: try `numbaOne[0]`...

Comment: no function? How could this written as a function? I'm really confused but am trying to figure this out.

Comment: I had numbaOne[0] in my original code.

Comment: tried it as function () { ... then my code and still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First of all, this isn't a function.

A function works like this:

CODE:

```
//function definition
function testFunction(param){
    console.log(param);
}

//function call
testFunction("hello");
```

OUTPUT:

```
hello
```

But there are a few more issues. `var numbaOne = [1,2,3];` is fine and appropriately gangsta. But the second part is not a valid JavaScript statement.

### You access an array this way:

```
//define array
var myArray = [1,2,3];

//get an element of that array
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

Those brackets `[]` are the important part.

## Your Function

So for your example, if you wanted a `function` that returned the first `element` of an `array` passed as a `parameter`, you would want something like this:

```
//make dat function
function numbaOne(myArrayHomie){
    //return the first element of what was passed to the function
    return myArrayHomie[0];
}
```

If we were to use this function, it would look something like this:

```
//some array
var blunt = [1,2,3];

//call the function and store result in a variable
var firstElementOfBlunt = numbaOne(blunt);

//print dat
console.log(firstElementOfBlunt);
```

OUTPUT: `1`

///EDIT///

Since it's a function, you can use that as many times as you want.

```
console.log(numbaOne(['my', 'homie', 'g']));
```

would print out `my`. That's what we mean by a `function`. You're putting that code block into something reusable, so that you could pass `numbaOne` any array and have it always return the first element.

Comment: var numbaOne = [8,2,3];   

var firstNumber = numbaOne[0];

console.log(firstNumber);

Comment: Yes. That is valid and would print out `8`. However, it still isn't a function. Meaning you couldn't use it again.

Comment: ok. thanks. how do I make that into a function? im really trying here, i know this is basic but that's where i am

Comment: im still a little confused man. im getting a sense of what you're saying but not sure how it all adds up for the intended outcome

Comment: yeah, a block of code that can be reused to get the same outcome?

Comment: Not necessarily the same outcome. More like regular outcomes. They take in things and spit other things out. You want a function that takes in an array and spits out the first element of it, yeah?

Comment: oh okay. yes, exactly.

Comment: Right. So we made a function called `numbaOne` that takes in an array and spits out the first element of it. If you're curious, this function is stored in memory the same way as a variable is

Comment: thats what i thought too. but why does my tutorial keep saying 'oop! try again"

Comment: would this work? 

function numbaOne(myArray){
    myArray = [9, 2, 3, 6];
    return myArray[0];
}
console.log(numbaOne([0]));

Comment: got it to work. thanks for the help without giving me the answer!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this function:

```
 function numbaOne(arr){
   return arr[0];
 }
 console.log(numbaOne([1,2,3,4,5]));
```